# Find the value of $a$ if the distance between $(3,-2)$ and $(4,a)$ is $\sqrt{7}$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

> Find the value of $a$ if the distance between $(3,-2)$ and $(4,a)$ is $\sqrt{7}$.

Do I use the distance formula with the variable or not?

Comment: *if the distance between $(3,-2)$ and $(4,a)$...* is **what**

Comment: There you go!!!

Comment: Can you help me now?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the distance formula is correct regardless of whether you are plugging in numbers or unknowns, so use the formula to get an expression for the distance involving $a$, and then set this expression equal to $\sqrt{7}$, and solve.

The distance between $(3,-2)$ and $(4,a)$ is
$$\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}=\sqrt{(4-3)^2+(a-(-2))^2}=\sqrt{(1)^2+(a+2)^2}=\sqrt{1+(a^2+4a+4)}=\sqrt{a^2+4a+5}$$
(this is our expression of the distance involving $a$). We're told that the distance is $\sqrt{7}$, and
$$\sqrt{a^2+4a+5}=\sqrt{7}\iff a^2+4a+5=7\iff a^2+4a-2=0.$$
Now use the quadratic formula to solve for $a$ (there will be two different values that work).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the quadratic equation..

Comment: @MarkZakhem When you have a second-degree equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, you can use the quadratic formula $x_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ to solve it (I assumed $x$ as your unknown variable, but in your case it's called $a$)

Comment: But how is it suppoused to solve both equations?

Comment: Just wondering.. is the answer below me correct

Comment: I done a couple lesson at tutoring on this yet I haven't seemed to get the hang of it.

Comment: The equation you have to solve already comes as $(a+2)^2+1=7$... There is no need for quadratic formula ;)

Answer (score 1):

$$d\big((3,-2),(4,a)\big)=\sqrt{7}$$ 
$$(3-4)^2+(-2-a)^2=7$$
$$1+4+4a+a^2=7$$
$$a^2+4a-2=0$$
$$a_{1,2}=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt 24}{2}=-2\pm\sqrt6$$
or
$$a_{1}=-2+\sqrt6,a_{2}=-2-\sqrt6$$

Comment: Just wondering, why is there a positive, negative sign instead of a comma?

Comment: positive sign is for $a_1$ and negative for $a_2$

Comment: But the negative sign is already on the 2...

Comment: So is a^1 -2 and a^2 sqrt 6?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Sometimes it helps to draw a diagram. 
Notice that there are 2 solutions. One at $(4,a_1)$ and one at $(4,a_2)$.
Just a reminder that $a_2$ does not mean $a$ to the power of $2$. It just means that the solution for $a$ comes from the set $\{a_1, a_2\}$. We could just as easily called these points $(4,b)$ and $(4,c)$, but using subscripts $(a_1$ and $a_2)$ is a bit cleaner.

Referring to the diagram, you can see 2 triangles with red outlines. Take the top one (it doesn't matter which one you chose; you will still get 2 solutions) and write out the Pythagorean formula.

$$(a-(-2))^2+1^2=\sqrt{7}^2$$
$$(a+2)^2+1=7$$
$$(a+2)^2=7-1$$
$$(a+2)^2=6$$
$$a+2=\pm \sqrt{6}$$
we have the $\pm$ because $(-\sqrt{6})^2=(+\sqrt{6})^2= 6$
$$a=-2 \pm \sqrt{6}$$
so splitting this into 2 solutions we have
$$a_1=-2 + \sqrt{6}$$
$$a_2=-2 - \sqrt{6}$$